# Why Url Encode From C# got Object Not Found in Codeigniter Controller?

Tags: c#, codeigniter, unity-game-engine, encryption

I have tried to convert the data from c# unity to URL encode in unity using `www.EscapeUrl`.

First, I encrypted the data using Rijndael with the text **My Name Is Dennis Putera, I am 31 Years Old and I am a Programmer** and I got the encrypted string is :

```
blO2QFSGtC9Ii1DKAaTpFbgZs4jTq6KwgWrCt/6RH0fji1yVubNDzXAmzkXy+JBqM88BJBy+rFyv4TTVy05t682ObIXBGrVqaQdbMo0VzUnNJdpbiQQVO3VoC07+JbNl
```

The I use `www.EscapeURL` to encode the text to pass to the controller in codeigniter :

```
blO2QFSGtC9Ii1DKAaTpFbgZs4jTq6KwgWrCt%2f6RH0fji1yVubNDzXAmzkXy%2bJBqM88BJBy%2brFyv4TTVy05t682ObIXBGrVqaQdbMo0VzUnNJdpbiQQVO3VoC07%2bJbNl
```

But when call the controller in CodeIgniter I got an error with

> OBJECT NOT FOUND

My full link URL in CodeIgniter is :

```
http://localhost/testing/index.php/manage/decryptRJ256/blO2QFSGtC9Ii1DKAaTpFbgZs4jTq6KwgWrCt%2f6RH0fji1yVubNDzXAmzkXy%2bJBqM88BJBy%2brFyv4TTVy05t682ObIXBGrVqaQdbMo0VzUnNJdpbiQQVO3VoC07%2bJbNl
```

which `Manage` is my controller and `decryptRJ256` is my function and the next is the parameter value.

Looks like CodeIgniter cannot read the parameter value.
Why I got an object not found on the page?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

GOT IT.

codeigniter cannot read the backslash url code %2f. so i have change the %2f and replace with other text and then change it back to %2f after passing the controller.

Comment: `urldecode()` and the usage of `GET` Parameter is most certainly the best option here. (Hasta Dhanas version is also legit)

Answer (score 1):

It's not CodeIgniter that cannot read the url parameter, it's the url encoding that cannot properly translate your parameter because it contains unallowed characters.
To convert it to allowed characters, try to convert it to `base64` as shown in here : [Base64 encode/decoding](https://answers.unity.com/questions/40568/base64-encodedecoding.html).

Then on the CodeIgniter side you could translate decoded string using PHP built `base64_decode()` function so it will preserve any characters within your parameter :

```
base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
```

This line gets the 3rd parameter.